# Optimizing jQuery Hotkeys

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, hotkeys

So I have a web app which uses all the hot keys from A to Z.

Each hot key is used for a tab. So for example:

I have 20 tabs:

`#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4` etc. All tabs get a class of `.tabs`.

So for the hotkeys to work I made this:

```
if (e.keyCode == 65) {$('.tabs:not(#tab1)').hide();$("#tab1").fadeIn();}
if (e.keyCode == 66) {$('.tabs:not(#tab2)').hide();$("#tab2").fadeIn();}
if (e.keyCode == 67) {$('.tabs:not(#tab3)').hide();$("#tab3").fadeIn();}
if (e.keyCode == 68) {$('.tabs:not(#tab4)').hide();$("#tab4").fadeIn();}
if (e.keyCode == 69) {$('.tabs:not(#tab5)').hide();$("#tab5").fadeIn();}
if (e.keyCode == 70) {$('.tabs:not(#tab6)').hide();$("#tab6").fadeIn();}
if (e.keyCode == 71) {$('.tabs:not(#tab7)').hide();$("#tab7").fadeIn();}
//etc till keycode 81 and tab20.
```

So, is there a **better optimizing way** to make this so it will be written in **less characters?** Since on each line I'm using twice the the same ID.

**Edit/Note:** Sorry, the actual tab ID's are random names.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 81) {
    var tab = e.keyCode - 65 + 1;
    $('.tabs:not(#tab' + tab + ')').hide();
    $('#tab' + tab).fadeIn();
}
```

I don't see how keycode 81 is supposed to be tab20 though, wouldn't that be tab17?

---

**Update**: If your tab `id`s can be anything at all then just throw them in an array:

```
var tab_ids = [ 'where', 'is', 'pancakes', 'house', ... ];
if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 81) {
    var tab = tab_ids[e.keyCode - 65];
    $('.tabs:not(#' + tab + ')').hide();
    $('#' + tab).fadeIn();
}
```

If you also have gaps in they keycodes then use an object instead of an array:

```
var tab_ids = { 65: 'where', 70: 'is', 72: 'pancakes', 73: 'house', ... };
var tab     = tab_ids[e.keyCode];
if(tab) {
    $('.tabs:not(#' + tab + ')').hide();
    $('#' + tab).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: This limits the tabs to literally be tab1, tab2 etc ? Sorry I haven't declared that the tabs are not tab1, tab2 etc, Are just random names. I named them as such for the demo purpose.

Comment: On ur edit: Well we haven't decided exactly the exact hotkey of the tabs. There are 3 more tabs left which we are thinking of which letters to use.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: So your tabs can have any old `id`s at all? How is the HTML structured?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Here is the actual working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3FHBy/ Try letters a b c. For 20 tabs, that way too much coding, don't you think? I was just hoping there is a way of optimizing it. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast: I added a few more options that might suit your situation.

Comment: Thank you. What you mean by gaps in the keycodes? EDIT: okay got it. Awesome thanks alot!

Comment: @jQuerybeast: If you're only using, say, "a-c" and "q-z" then you'd have a gap from "d" to "p".

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tabs:not(#tab' + (e.keyCode - 64) + ')').hide();
$("#tab" + (e.keyCode - 64)).fadeIn();
```

Comment: This limits the tabs to literally be tab1, tab2 etc ? Sorry I haven't declared that the tabs are not tab1, tab2 etc, Are just random names. I named them as such for the demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all these if statements with this code

```
$('.tabs:not(#tab'+(e.keyCode-64)+')').hide();
$("#tab"+(e.keyCode-64)).fadeIn();
```